# In countries using Single Transferable Vote, how are voting results presented?

Tags: voting-systems, single-transferable-vote

In electoral systems based on parties, it is easy to publish the results: it is sufficient to publish the number of votes each party received. These numbers contain all the information that is needed to compute the election outcome.

But in [single transferable vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote), each voter votes by ranking the candidates. The potential number of different votes is the factorial of the number of candidates, which may be enormous. It may be impossible to publish all these results.

Is there an efficient way to publish the results of STV elections, such that the published information can be used by observers to compute the election outcome?

Comment: In practice, if there are n candidates, at it takes r rounds to determine a winner, only npr categories are relevant, not n!. And I would expect them to just publish the vote totals at each round, not the full ballots.

Comment: @Acccumulation what is "npr categories"?

Comment: Read as "n pick r", computed as (n! / (n-r)!). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I did a lot of revisions. I intended to write nPr, but it ended up npr.

Comment: They usually publish the results for round one (first preference, all candidates), then round 2 (first preference is still in the running, otherwise second preference), and so on, don't they?

Comment: See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Alaska%27s_at-large_congressional_district_special_election#Results_2

Comment: Not what you asked, but a simpler example: In the UK we often have local elections where two representatives are elected at the same time. Everyone gets two votes among a single list of candidates, and the significant parties field two candidates each (independents are still just one candidate). The results are reported as the number of votes for each candidate, *not* as all the combinations of two people voted for. So the result doesn't tell you how many occurrences there were of unusual things like one Red vote and one Blue vote on the same ballot.

Comment: Anecdotally I can say that it's not in the least unusual for the two winning candidates from the same party to end up on different numbers of votes. It would be faintly interesting to know whether this is because of mixed voting, or how many voters selected only one candidate despite being entitled to select two. But the published result doesn't tell you.

Comment: In fact I think there would be some danger in publishing that full list. Ideally in an electoral system it should be impossible to prove how you voted, to help reduce vote buying and coercion. But if your vote can be made unique, and then your exact choice is published, that more or less proves you really did what you said you would / were told to do. This would only be weak evidence with two votes, but for STV your full list of preferences could *easily* be unique, especially if there are a few irrelevant joke candidates you can tag on the end in a pre-agreed order.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's consider the classic example: **Australia**, which has used STV/IRV for more than a century.

For calculations of votes, we need to consider each electorate separately. Calculation of the global outcome (seats won etc.) is trivial.

It should be noted that in *any* voting system, tallying the final result given "the number of votes each party received" is a technical process and is rarely controversial. The process is more complicated for STV, but it's still pure math. Controversy may arise at the earlier stages: how exactly ballots are counted, what is considered informal (invalid) vote, how ballots are presented, etc. This is where most scrutiny is needed.

Generally, for the public, the results are presented already calculated and ranked. They still present the "number of votes" for each candidate, but this number is calculated in a less trivial manner than just adding up votes. Still, the process of calculation is also presented for those who are interested.

[Here is an example](https://results.aec.gov.au/27966/Website/HouseDivisionPage-27966-179.htm) from the most recent federal elections for the electorate of Adelaide. (This is the lower house election, which is IRV - a single winner version of STV. It is a bit easier to demonstrate, but the principle is the same. Note that Senate is still elected by candidates, not parties; just there are multiple winners in the last round and the threshold is lower than 50%).

The (abbreviated) "final" table looks rather "normal":

| Candidate | Votes | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GRANTHAM, Amy | 42,948 | 38.09 |
| GEORGANAS, Steve | 69,816 | 61.91 |

The catch is that there are only two candidates shown out of 7! This is because other candidates were eliminated in the STV counting process, and their votes were redistributed to these candidates. This is essentially the result of the last round of counting. In Australia, this is often called **Two party preferred** or **Two candidate preferred** result.

Next thing presented (and often publicised) is the **First preference count** for *each* candidate. This is the exact number of ballots which gave first preference ("1") to this candidate, like if it were "traditional" elections. We can see that for these two candidates, the count is different and much lower:

| Candidate | Votes | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GRANTHAM, Amy | 36,080 | 32.00 |
| GEORGANAS, Steve | 45,086 | 39.98 |

In STV, this first preference count has largely psychological/symbolic value. In this example, we can see that a third of votes for the ultimate winner Steve came from other parties, whereas Amy had much higher share of "personal" votes. Of course, it is a well-known feature of STV that the final winner may not be the one who had the most first-preference votes.

Nevertheless, there is an "implementation detail" in Australia that parties/candidates who get enough first-preference votes (a fairly small percentage) get certain monetary compensation for the election expenses. This is to avoid a flood of spurious candidates who might register just "for fun".

The next thing one may wish to examine is the **Full distribution of preferences** table on the same page. There, each round of counting is presented, starting from *first preference* and culminating in the *two candidate preferred* result. It is clearly observable how, for example, the 870 votes from the first-eliminated candidate are distributed to the remaining 6 candidates in the second round, and so on.

Here, by the way, is where Senate election with its multi-winner count gets more complicated. There, if a candidate gets more votes than the quota requires (at any round), the "excess" votes are taken away and redistributed to other candidates with the proportional weight. As a result, each elected candidate gets exactly the same number of votes in the final round, and everyone else gets 0! This is not required for IRV as such process will not change the ultimate winner. The calculation is also published, but it is a multi-page PDF document ([example](https://results.aec.gov.au/27966/Website/External/SenateStateDop-27966-TAS.pdf) of a smaller one for Tasmania - 30 pages).

For those who want to scrutinise further, AEC [publishes the results](https://results.aec.gov.au/27966/Website/HouseDownloadsMenu-27966-Csv.htm) in machine-readable formats as well.

Comment: Regarding the last link, I am not sure I understand: do they publish every individual vote?

Comment: technically, if we're talking Australian federal elections, STV has been used since 1948, so less than a century. Though individual states have used it for their legislatures for longer.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi No, they don't publish individual votes. The publish how pools of votes flow through the redistribution process. For example, if a candidate gets eliminated, you can see how the votes for that candidate are redistributed to the remaining candidates.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Looks like for the senate they do however publish individual votes.

Comment: Very nice explanation. But your counting in the paragraph after the second table looks off. Steve got 45 thousand first preference votes and 70 thousand votes total, so well more than half are first preference. Of course it doesn't need to be that way, in theory you can have 0 first preference votes and still win but this isn't the case here.

Comment: @quarague, well, I was thinking with respect to the first preference votes: final > 1.5*first. But as worded, you are right, I'll fix that. My point though was simply that the "preference share" of the final count is larger for the winner (in this specific case) than for the runner-up; some intuitively feel this is "cheating", but this is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That’s a function of how the votes are counted: for the House of Representatives the votes are counted by hand (essentially by sorting them into piles based on the current preference state). The Senate ballot papers are scanned into a computer which computes the preference flow, so they have every single vote available in a digital form.

Comment: +1 Very helpful. A clear explanation and answer in the Australian context.

Comment: Publishing all the individual votes helps serves an election integrity function, as it means nobody has to trust that the election software carried out the STV process correctly, as anyone can recompute the results themselves based on the individual votes. You, of course, still have to trust that the reported individual votes accurately represent the valid votes cast, but that's the same concern you'd have in any non-STV election, and there are various audit and public inspection procedures used in all types of elections to provide assurance of that.

Comment: If someone received almost no first-choice votes, but ended up receiving enough second-choice votes to win the election, would they be reimbursed for election expenses as a result of second-choice votes being promoted to first-choice votes, or would their lack of first-choice votes in the initial round preclude reimbursement?

Comment: @ZachLipton interestingly, it's not clear that "trust that the election software carried out the STV process correctly" is actually a concern for the AEC. There was a court case a few years back to try and get the code's source made available for scrutiny, but the AEC fought against it *hard*, and actually got the plaintiff declared a "vexatious applicant". (search: "mjec EasyCount" for details)

Comment: @supercat, as far as I know, compensation is paid only on first-preference votes. The threshold is [4% for federal elections](https://www.aec.gov.au/media/2022/06-20c.htm), but each state can have different rules. Technically, everyone who didn't get to the last round gets 0 votes, so the only sensible discriminator is the first round. Intuitively, "if nobody wants _you_, you don't deserve compensation". I'm not aware of a practical case when someone gets <4% first round but then wins, although for Senate it's not unthinkable (the threshold is applied per party/group there).

Comment: @Zeus: I think the minimum number of first-place votes to achieve victory without ties at any stage of the election would be two votes (not 2%--just two votes) if there are enough candidates and votes split just right.  If Mr. X gets two first-choice votes, and there's one vote for A/X, two for B/X, four for C/X, Eight for D/X, etc. then Mr. X would could end up with a majority of the total votes, regardless of how many total votes there are.

Comment: @supercat In theory, I think you could win an election under STV with *zero* first-preference votes. This is because in STV, before the lowest-ranked candidates are eliminated, any surplus votes over the quota are redistributed. A candidate with zero 1st-preference votes could get enough from these redistributions to avoid being eliminated themselves, and allow them to harvest votes from eliminated candidates. In reality, the likelihood of this is exceedingly low, verging on zero. But it is theoretically possible.

Comment: @JimCullen: A candidate can't receive transfer votes from candidates who have more first-choice votes, and their ability to receive transfer votes from others who have the same number would depend upon tie-break rules that aren't always handled the same way (I don't know how AU handles them), and if a competing candidate doesn't receive any first-choice votes, that will mean there aren't any ballots whose second choice would be promoted by their elimination.

Comment: @supercat, I think this _can_ happen, but only in multi-winner STV. Imagine 3 candidates, 2 to win => quota ~33%. Popular candidate A gets 99% first-preference, B 1%, C 0%. What happens next is that A gets a seat, and the excess 66% for A redistributed to others with weight 2/3. If it happens that all (100%) who voted for A prefer C over B, then C gets 66% and B remains with 1%. C wins the second seat. That is, if we stop here. We can do the next step and redistribute the excess 33% for C to B, who will then get 34%. I'm not entirely sure it's required at the last round...

Comment: @supercat you may be thinking of Instant Runoff Voting, also known as "ranked choice voting" or the "alternative vote". It's a special case of STV where the number of candidates who can win is 1. Usually, if someone says STV, they mean any circumstance *other* than where N=1, because when N=1 there's another name for it. Zeus's comment more or less explains how this would work.

Answer (score 10):

Adding on further context to Zeus's very good answer:

In **Australia**, where the Senate results are done using STV on a per-state level, voters are allowed to vote for a party as a whole, rather than being required to vote for each candidate individually. This is called "above-the-line" voting. The vast majority of voters choose this path, though the option still exists to number each candidate individually ("below-the-line").

The headline figure seen most often is the number of first preference votes cast above-the-line, or the sum of the party's above-the-line votes and the votes given to each candidate below-the-line. [See this page for the Queensland results of the last election](https://results.aec.gov.au/27966/Website/SenateStateFirstPrefs-27966-QLD.htm) for an example.

In reality, to make them more consumable, these raw vote counts/percentages are often converted into "quotas", representing the fractions of a seat that have been won by that party.

| Group | Candidate | Party | Votes | % | Quotas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J | Above-the-line Votes | Queensland Greens | 345,470 | 11.46 | 0.8024 |
|  | **ALLMAN-PAYNE, Penny** | Queensland Greens | 21,671 | 0.72 | 0.0503 |
|  | SRI, Anna | Queensland Greens | 1,718 | 0.06 | 0.0040 |
|  | Group Total | Queensland Greens | 373,460 | 12.39 | 0.8674 |
| S | Above-the-line Votes | Liberal National Party of Queensland | 1,013,227 | 33.62 | 2.3533 |
|  | **McGRATH, James** | Liberal National Party of Queensland | 21,411 | 0.71 | 0.0497 |
|  | **CANAVAN, Matt** | Liberal National Party of Queensland | 11,822 | 0.39 | 0.0275 |
|  | STOKER, Amanda | Liberal National Party of Queensland | 11,981 | 0.40 | 0.0278 |
|  | Group Total | Liberal National Party of Queensland | 1,061,638 | 35.23 | 2.4658 |
| Y | Above-the-line Votes | Australian Labor Party | 713,051 | 23.66 | 1.6561 |
|  | **WATT, Murray** | Australian Labor Party | 21,847 | 0.72 | 0.0507 |
|  | **CHISHOLM, Anthony** | Australian Labor Party | 2,183 | 0.07 | 0.0051 |
|  | Group Total | Australian Labor Party | 744,212 | 24.69 | 1.7285 |

Note that the "group total" counts are indicative only, and not of any formal value in the ballot count.

From this table you can see that Penny Allman-Payne received 0.85 quotas on first preferences (above the line group J votes give first preference to her), meaning she needs to receive 0.15 more quotas in subsequent round to get elected. James McGrath received 2.4, so he passes 1.4 quotas down to second preferences, at least 1.35 of which will *definitely* go to Matt Canavan (because above-the-line group S votes give second preference to Canavan). So Canavan receives at least 1.37, and passes at least 0.35 to Amanda Stoker, who therefore is guaranteed at least 0.37 quotas.

For most people, this high-level count is sufficient. Guesses at how many total quotas a candidate will receive can be made by an understanding of party preferences. For example, "Animal Justice Party" above-the-line voters are likely to preference the Greens, while "One Nation" voters probably preference the LNP. So Greens' total quotas can be estimated by adding their own first preference vote to the vote of AJP, as long as you assume AJP candidates will not win a seat, and their voters will not preference a different party which *does* win a seat first.

For those who want to fully validate the election results, a full list of every formal vote is published. So is a summary of the distributions of preferences at each round of the count. [You can see the links to these for the 2022 election here.](https://results.aec.gov.au/27966/Website/SenateDownloadsMenu-27966-Csv.htm) You can also get counts of things like how many votes were informal (often referred to as "spoilt" ballots, i.e. ballots which were not filled out in a way that allows them to be counted).

Answer (score 6):

In the case of New York City's latest mayoral primary the data was made available in the form of a [collection of CSV files](https://www.vote.nyc/page/election-results-summary#p0) (click on 'Download CVR data').  There's no metadata or readme accompanying it, but Alec Barrett has published an 'unofficial' readme on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/anbnyc/282646575f41fabf41da239cbc9ace1f). This data was previously used on Politics.SE to calculate the [Condorcet winner](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/68328/7434) of that primary.

I suspect that the same method of releasing data is used in all jurisdictions where STV is used.

Comment: Might be worth looking at Alaska data as they use ranked choice as well if my memory is right.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Does it mean that every individual vote is published?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi yes every single vote is published.